# Is there a way to programatically access the category type of an Android .apk?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know what kind of application is being used.  The play store allows you to specify categories for .apks (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113475?hl=en&ref_topic=2897459).

I'd like a way to query this at runtime, but I don't see any related APIs.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This information is in the Play Store. It is not in the APK, and hence is not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

library and example query for apk category are [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps):